# The Virtual Device is unable to connect

Tags: dart, android-studio, debugging, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

My Virtual device is well installed because it runs independently but when i attempt to run throough the run/debug configuration i get an error.

I tried installing a new system image but it still doesn't run and I also tried to run with Chrome and it worked.

Comment: please share the error you are getting